# using Cloudformation ref with awscli in userData

Tags: aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

```
"aws ec2 create-tags --resources xxxxxx --tags Key=Team,Value=everybody --region { \"Ref\" : \"region\" } --out text\n"
```

The above line/command I am using in my Cloudformation userData, It is not getting executed , I am getting the following error when I debugged :

```
aws: error: argument --region: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

ap-southeast-1 | us-gov-west-1 
ap-northeast-1 | eu-west-1 
fips-us-gov-west-1 | us-west-1 
us-west-2 | us-east-1 
cn-north-1 | ap-southeast-2 
sa-east-1
```

My region name is taken as input parameter for Cloudformation script. Thats why I used `ref` in `--region` option.

Is this wrong ?
Is it possible to use `ref` with awscli commands in Cloudformation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserData` is a string in your Cloud Formation template, and therefore the `{"Ref": "region"}` is not expanded so the literal `{"Ref": "region"}` is being passed to the `--region` argument.

you could try

```
{"Fn::Join": [" ", ["aws ec2 create-tags --resources xxxxxx --tags Key=Team,Value=everybody --region", {"Ref": "region"}, "--out text\n"]]}
```

The docs provide information on the `Fn::Join` function http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

Also this example template shows `UserData` including a `Ref` for the region parameter

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/vpc_single_instance_in_subnet.template