# Change variables in user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Here is a cloudformation template that works as expected.

https://github.com/shantanuo/cloudformation/blob/master/updated/so2.tpl.txt

But when I change the last line to something like this...

```
/home/ec2-user/mysecret.txt`'' --valid-ips  !Ref MyIpAddress >
```

It silently ignores the command. Is there any other way to substitute the MyIpAddress variable?

Comment: What is `MyIpAddress`? I couldn't see it in the template.

Comment: 18.210.57.140 is the replaced value of variable MyIpAddress

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314105/using-cloudformation-ref-with-awscli-in-userdata
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775534/reference-parameter-value-in-userdata-in-aws-cloudformation

Comment: @PatMyron that solved the problem. Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it? Or can you explain why --valid-ips  !Ref MyIpAddress did not work?

Comment: [Fn::Join docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'Fn::Join' you can use 'Fn::Sub'. This will make your template more readable as won't have to break your script inot multiple lines and you can reference MyIpAddress as ${MyIpAddress}.

Comment: Is there a tool that will change Join to Sub?

Comment: No there is not. You can change it yourself, just write script without line breaks and in the places where you need to substitute any resource add ${variable_name}.

Comment: I tried writing the script without line breaks and it is not readable anymore. Nor can I change it easily. Can you suggest how can I use Join and still substitute?

Comment: Can you post a snippet after using the Sub function?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how and why does it work. But this is what I was looking for.

```
              - >-
                /usr/local/bin/aws-ec2-assign-elastic-ip --access-key ''`cat
                /home/ec2-user/myaccesskey.txt`''  --secret-key ''`cat
                /home/ec2-user/mysecret.txt`'' --valid-ips '
              - !Ref MyIpAddress
              - |
                '
```

Thanks to Pat's comment!